# .NET MAUI How to make a proper Gridlayout in Collectionview with Header?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I'm trying to build a table in .NET MAUI based on a Grid Layout. This is the code:

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding digitalInputs}">
    <CollectionView.Header>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*">
            <Label Text="Name" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="Typ" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Status" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Label Text="Aktiv" Grid.Column="3"/>
        </Grid>
    </CollectionView.Header>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="services:DigitalInput">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*">
                <Label Text="{Binding pName}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding pDigitalType}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding pValueText}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding pActive}" Grid.Column="3"/>
             </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

This is the result when running in Debug Mode on MacCatalyst (Visual Studio for Mac):

[image: MAUI Macos screenshot]

Now I wonder how I can align the header grid properly to the grid in the data template? Does someone have a suggestion on how I can improve the code to build a proper table?

**Edit:** This seems to be a bug in the IDE. When I change the `HorizontalOptions` property on the Grid in the `CollectionView.Header`, as a comment suggested, the XAML Hot-Reload triggers a re-rendering of the view and all of a sudden the header grid aligns correctly with the grid in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I would expect this to work. If you set a unique bg color on each Label in the header you can visualize the size of each one.  It seems like it things the container for the header grid is larger than it really is.  Possibly set the Horizontal options to "Fill" or "FillAndExpand"?

Comment: When I change the property while running the app in debug mode, the XAML HotReload triggers a re-render of the view and the grid becomes aligned perfectly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the code you provided in **iOS**, **Windows** in `MAUI`. And it can **align** the header grid properly to the grid in the data template in CollectionView. So the issue could be related with the `services:DigitalInput` retrieving the data, they should be correctly formatted with no blank space in those properties.

Below are the code sample and running output, hope it can shed some light for you!

**XAML:**

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding digitalInputs}"> 

        <CollectionView.Header>
 
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*">
                <Label Text="Name" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Typ" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Status" Grid.Column="2"/>
                <Label Text="Aktiv" Grid.Column="3"/>
            </Grid>
        </CollectionView.Header>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate >

                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*">

                    <Label Text="{Binding pName}" Grid.Column="0"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding pDigitalType}" Grid.Column="1"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding pValueText}" Grid.Column="2"/>

                    <Label Text="{Binding pActive}" Grid.Column="3"/>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
    public ObservableCollection<Model> digitalInputs { get; set; } 
    public NewPage1()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            //assign data
            digitalInputs = new ObservableCollection<Model>()
            {

                  new Model{pName="KipSchalter", pDigitalType="Zustand",pActive="OFF", pValueText="True" },
                  new Model{pName="KipSchalter", pDigitalType="Zustand",pActive="OFF", pValueText="True" },
                  new Model{pName="Digital In 3", pDigitalType="Zustand",pActive="OFF", pValueText="FALSE" },
                  new Model{pName="Digital In 4", pDigitalType="Zustand",pActive="OFF", pValueText="FALSE" }
        }
            ;

            BindingContext = this;
      }
```

**iOS output:**

[image]

**Windows output:**
[image]

**Update:**

This seems to be a potential issue in the IDE. When changing the `HorizontalOptions` property on the Grid as Jason suggested, the header grid aligns correctly with the grid in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: The problem actually occurs to me only when running on MacCatalyst Debug Mode, I should've said that.

Comment: @fonzane No worries, I noticed that changing the `HorizontalOptions` property worked. Please help accept it as answer as it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, changing the HorizontalOptions property seems to trigger a re-rendering through the XAML Hot-Reload and corrects the initial false rendering. I'm experiencing more issues in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by arranging children horizontally first and then pushing down to the next row then the current MAUI still does not support that, you can only trigger span (also span isn't changing at runtime on WinUI right now, I think the team is fixing it) or create a custom one

```
    public class HorizontalWrapLayout : StackLayout
{
    public HorizontalWrapLayout()
    {
    }

    protected override ILayoutManager CreateLayoutManager()
    {
        return new HorizontalWrapLayoutManager(this);
    }
}



    public class HorizontalWrapLayoutManager : StackLayoutManager
{
    HorizontalWrapLayout _layout;

    public HorizontalWrapLayoutManager(HorizontalWrapLayout horizontalWrapLayout) : base(horizontalWrapLayout)
    {
        _layout = horizontalWrapLayout;
    }

    public override Size Measure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        var padding = _layout.Padding;

        widthConstraint -= padding.HorizontalThickness;

        var rows = new Dictionary<int, List<Size>>();
        var currentRowIndex = 0;
        var currentRow = new List<Size>();

        rows.Add(currentRowIndex, currentRow);

        foreach (var child in _layout)
        {
            if (child.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var childSize = child.Measure(double.PositiveInfinity, heightConstraint);
            var childWidth = childSize.Width + (currentRow.Any() ? _layout.Spacing : 0);

            var rowWidth = currentRow.Aggregate(0.0, (w, x) => w + x.Width);
            if (rowWidth + childWidth > widthConstraint)
            {
                if (currentRow.Any())
                {
                    currentRowIndex++;
                    currentRow = new List<Size>();
                    rows.Add(currentRowIndex, currentRow);
                }
            }
            else if (currentRow.Any())
            {
                currentRow.Add(new Size(_layout.Spacing, 0));
            }

            currentRow.Add(childSize);
        }

        var totalWidth = 0.0;
        var totalHeight = 0.0;

        if (rows.Any())
        {
            var rowWidths = rows.Select(x => x.Value.Aggregate(0.0, (result, item) => result + item.Width)).ToList();
            var rowHeights = rows.Select(x => x.Value.Any() ? x.Value.Max(i => i.Height) : 0).ToList();

            totalWidth = rowWidths.Any() ? rowWidths.Max() : 0;
            totalHeight = rowHeights.Any() ? rowHeights.Sum() : 0;
            if (rows.Keys.Count > 1)
            {
                totalHeight += _layout.Spacing * (rows.Keys.Count - 1);
            }
        }

        totalWidth += padding.HorizontalThickness;
        totalHeight += padding.VerticalThickness;

        var finalHeight = ResolveConstraints(heightConstraint, Stack.Height, totalHeight, Stack.MinimumHeight, Stack.MaximumHeight);
        var finalWidth = ResolveConstraints(widthConstraint, Stack.Width, totalWidth, Stack.MinimumWidth, Stack.MaximumWidth);

        return new Size(finalWidth, finalHeight);
    }

    public override Size ArrangeChildren(Rect bounds)
    {
        var padding = Stack.Padding;
        double top = padding.Top + bounds.Top;
        double left = padding.Left + bounds.Left;

        double currentRowTop = top;
        double currentX = left;
        double currentRowHeight = 0;

        double maxStackWidth = currentX;

        for (int n = 0; n < _layout.Count; n++)
        {
            var child = _layout[n];

            if (child.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (currentX + child.DesiredSize.Width > bounds.Right)
            {
                // Keep track of our maximum width so far
                maxStackWidth = Math.Max(maxStackWidth, currentX);

                // Move down to the next row
                currentX = left;
                currentRowTop += currentRowHeight + _layout.Spacing;
                currentRowHeight = 0;
            }

            var destination = new Rect(currentX, currentRowTop, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height);
            child.Arrange(destination);

            currentX += destination.Width + _layout.Spacing;
            currentRowHeight = Math.Max(currentRowHeight, destination.Height);
        }

        var actual = new Size(maxStackWidth, currentRowTop + currentRowHeight);

        return actual.AdjustForFill(bounds, Stack);
    }
```

Usage

```
<app:HorizontalWrapLayout
            BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{x:StaticResource HorizontalWrapLayoutItemTemplate}"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ControlGroups, Mode=OneWay}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Spacing="50"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
```